# In Neovim/Vim, how to set keymaps so that everything uses them including plugins and other commands

Tags: neovim

I am a beginner. My problem is that my layout is not US and I have no separate '[' ']' keys. Instead, I have some local ğ and ü keys. I'd like to bind them to [ and ] so that these keys act like the brackets in every single possible situation except for insert mode. The problem is that they work in a limited way. For example, actual ]] jumps to the end of the file while üü doesn't do that. Or using nvim-surround, if I go ds[, it deletes the nearest [ ] pair around while dsğ does nothing. I also tried binding <C-ğ> to <Esc> but that doesn't work either.

I tried putting the mappings in a separate file in the after folder AND I tried moving them to the first lines of init.lua. It doesn't work. It looks like they only work when they are used once and on their own, they don't combine with other plugins etc.

Here are the mappings:

```
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'ğ', '[', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'ü', ']', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'Ğ', '{', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o'}, 'Ü', '}', {remap = true})
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v', 'o', 'i'}, '<C-ğ>', '<Esc>')
```

What I want to achieve is that I want these keys to be the exact same for anything. Is this possible WITHOUT system settings? I want this to be a nvim exclusive option

**Edit:** The option I was looking for was langmap and langremap. If you :set these like in my case:

```
vim.o.langmap = "ğ[,ü],Ğ{,Ü}"
vim.o.langremap = true
```

it works. It probably has some downsides but I can't seem to find them at the moment

Comment: why are you even using the keymap api instead of just writign `nmap ü ]` in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I'm using Neovim and my configs are Lua files. I just realised I forgot to put that in the title. From what I know, it's the exact same functionality as what you wrote, just nvim compatible. I tested this mapping in Vim as well but it doesn't work there either

Comment: Read about `:h 'keymap'` as this is exactly feature meant for people with such problem.

Comment: @Hauleth if I understand correctly, this allows me to use custom keyboard layouts, so I could change the useless keys to something like the US layout? But the problem is that I still need those ğ ü letters in insert mode and map them to [ ] in other modes, but keymap seems to only work in insert mode. I need the opposite

Comment: @lee_evernote I'd suggest removing the edit to your question and instead post the solution you found as an answer below. If you're satisfied with the answer, then also accept it. Doing so follows Stack Overflow guidelines and also helps people quickly see that an answer exists.